# Global variable / state in React (with React router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and trying to build a website with dark mode.

by changing the data-theme in CSS file when the toggle button is clicked, and the following is my file structure in `App.jsx`.

```
├── Header
│   └── DarkModeToggle
├── Content
│
└── (CSS file)
```

***DarkModeToggle.jsx***

```
class NightModeToggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            theme: 'light',
        }
        this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this);
    }

    toggleTheme() {
        const theme = this.state.theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
        this.setState({ theme });
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
    }

    render() {...}
}
```

I also use react route so that I can display different information in different URL

***Content.jsx***

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/test' component={Test}></Route>
                        <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
                        <Route exact path='/project' component={Project}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

***However,*** the website cannot keep the theme when I go to other URL.

For example, I change to dark mode in `/home` and then I go to `/project`, the website will back to the light mode.

How can I maintain the `theme` variable (or init a global variable) when I using React-Route? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you checked this [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) from `react` to create global context.

Then you can wrap your app file within context you have created.

Now you can access themeMode from any file inside react render tree.

Below is example, how you can use themeMode with context API

#### Context

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AppContext = createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState("lightTheme");

  const value = { themeMode };

  return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

export default AppProvider;
```

#### Index

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import AppProvider from "./AppProvider";

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppProvider>
    <App />
  </AppProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

#### App

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./AppProvider";

const App = () => {
  const { themeMode } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log("THEME MODE: ", themeMode);
  return <div></div>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use styled components for theming the web app.

Please refer this link for more info:

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming